# string variable containing anything + com.xx gets (class) inserted

Tags: google-apps-script, rhino, google-apps-script-editor

This might be a bug in Google Scripts, or perhaps I am doing something wrong. If I include a country suffix com.xx in a string variable, it gets replaced with "(class)". Just "com" is fine, but anything after that triggers this.

Here are my two variables

`var VarA = 'https://example.com.au/projects.json' ;
var VarB = 'https://example.com/projects.json' ;`

When I debug this, they behave differently. B is fine, but A gets (class) inserted

`VarA  string   "https://example.(class)/projects.json" 
VarB  string   "https://example.com/projects.json"`

Update: when I first posted this (13 Nov) this was occurring in all three:

1. logger
2. debug
3. when passed to another function to get that URL

It is now working for logger and when passed to a function. Still occurring in debug mode, but I am guessing this was a bug that was addressed

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case during debugging http://prntscr.com/h9vyfi  Placing the breakpoint after 'VarA' is assigned a value produces this wrong result in the console. However, in my case, it doesn't affect the Logger http://prntscr.com/h9vzly  Could that be a Debugger console parser issue?

Comment: I've verified that this isn't an issue in the debugger. When I send VarA  through to another function, it will fail at run time with an error along the lines of "that isn't a valid URL" (since example.(class)/blah isn't): `Request failed for https://example.<?>/projects.json returned code 401.`

Comment: Without an example I can't verify the behavior.  What are you trying to do when this replacement occurs?

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/a/redant.com.au/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQk0rcu8zl0yQz6lXCZdOomhlv8oEtbN2NRgjbaJgzk1hVbHx8VlKtAh5Fu-XAGLEZZHQziZMoFhURg/pubhtml

Comment: I think something may have been updated - this behaviour (when you include a country suffix replaced with (class) was occurring in all three: logger, console, and when passed to another function. Now only seems to be occurring in debug mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["com.au" string is displayed as "(class)" in Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231226/com-au-string-is-displayed-as-class-in-script-editor)